# Example finitely generated solvable group that has infinite Prufer rank.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does there exist a finitely generated solvable group that has infinite Prufer rank?

A group has finite Prufer rank $r$ if every finitely generated subgroup can be generated by $r$ elements and $r$ is the least such integer. Otherwise it has infinite Prufer rank.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave some context to your question: Where did you come across if? What have you tried? You earlier asked a rather elementary question, again without context. This makes me wonder where they all cone from...

Comment: I am currently learning about Prufer rank and I like to wonder about in the topic.

Comment: Let $F$ be a nonabelian free group of finite rank. Then $F/F''$ is solvable and $F'/F''$ is free abelian of infinite rank.

Comment: The wreath product of two copies of the integers should also provide an example.